# how to store a token in react native

Tags: react-native

i am new to react native i am trying to store the generated token from API to a storage so I can access it from anywhere in my application  the generated token Is available in `response.data.token` i want to store it in something like `session storage` or `local storage` to access it from

```
  axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register',
      data: Data,
     
    })

      .then(response => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(response.data.token));

      })
     
      .catch(error => {
       alert(JSON.stringify(error.response.data));
      });
  }
```

also pls let me know  how i can check for if the token is stored in  `React Native debugger`

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage is closest to session/local storage in RN.

Comment: @user18309290 could u help how i can use it with an answer

Comment: hope this will help you https://blog.jscrambler.com/how-to-use-react-native-asyncstorage

Answer (score 1):

You have to use  `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` library to store the token in LocalStorage.

After that use it like this.

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

axios({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register',
  data: Data,
 
})

  .then(response => {
  alert(JSON.stringify(response.data.token));
  AsyncStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(response.data.token));
  })
 
  .catch(error => {
   alert(JSON.stringify(error.response.data));
  });
}
```

Actually there is no exact way to check that token is available in the LocalStorage or not but you can `console.log()` it and check.

For checking it.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserToken = async () => {
     const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token'); 
       console.log("token",token)   
    };
    getUserToken();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Redux** to Store the Session Token
and with useSelector you can access token all over the app .

You can go through with these documentations
[Link 1](https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/securing-react-redux-apps-with-jwt-tokens-fcfe81356ea0)
[Link 2](https://blog.logrocket.com/handling-user-authentication-redux-toolkit/)

Comment: i dont want to use redux

Comment: Check this:
https://www.bezkoder.com/react-jwt-auth/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to save some data in an unsecured way and access it from anywhere, then yes, Async Storage is your option.

Just install the Async Storage like that:

```
yarn add @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```

And then in any async function, you can call this to set data:

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem('your_data_identifier', data);
```

And call this to get data:

```
const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('your_data_identifier');
```

More here https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/

If you want a more secure way, there are a few libs, like this for example:
https://github.com/talut/rn-secure-storage